# Is the Russell set a proper class in $ZFC$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Kunen"s "Set Theory" on page 21, defines the Russell set as $R:\{x:x\notin x\}$.

In the context of $ZFC$, not set can be an element of itself.

Then would $R$ be a proper class since it would include all sets and not be a set by virtue of Burali-Forti?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly (though you do not need B-F)

Comment: Yes, it is a proper class. In ZFC it is the class of all sets. In non-well-founded set theories that have sets that contain themselves, it will not be the class of all sets, but still must be a proper class to avoid paradox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R$ is indeed a proper class.

A simple, self-contained proof of this fact is the argument of Russell's paradox, which derives a contradiction from the hypothesis that $R$ is a set.

A virtue of this proof is that it remains valid in Z; the axiom of foundation plays no role in the argument.

---

Commonly, the fact $R$ is a proper class is used to *prove* the class of all sets is proper, since if there was a set of all sets, $R$ must also be a set by the axiom of subsets.